# Name for this kind of integral that is logarithmically divergent in a parameter?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, terminology

Suppose $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are a real-valued rapidly decaying functions that smoothly approach $1$ as $x\rightarrow 1$. For example,

$$f(x)=e^{-x}, \,g(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Now consider the following function defined through an integral:

$$F(\alpha)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x+\alpha g(x)}dx$$

Suppose you would like to study the small-$\alpha$ behavior of $F(\alpha)$. You can clearly see that if $\alpha=0$, the integrand is logarithmically singular near $x=0$. Also, if you analytically continue $\alpha$, it is clear that $F(\alpha)$ is singular along the entire negative-real axis.

Therefore, I expect the analytic small-$\alpha$ behavior to look like a logarithm

$$F(\alpha)\approx F_0\textrm{Log}(\alpha)+\mathcal{O}(\alpha\,\textrm{Log}\alpha)$$

**Is there a name for integrals defined like $F(\alpha)$? Or maybe something similar?**

Comment: Numerically, it seems that $F(\alpha)/\ln(\alpha) \to -0.99$, which I guess should be limit $-1$.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not looking for the leading-order behavior for the specific choices of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that I provided. My question is far more general than that. I'm looking for a general class of integrals that my $F(\alpha)$ is part of. I only provided examples of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ to illustrate my point. I want to know more properties of such functions/integrals.